# rerunning agg on pandas groupby object modifies the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to aggregate a bunch of dictionaries, with string keys and lists of binary numbers as values, stored in a pandas dataframe. Like this:

Example dataframe that this problem occurs with:

```
df4 
subject task_nr probe_dict
0   2   1   {'1_3': [0, 0, 1, 1]}
1   2   0   {'1_3': [0, 0, 1, 1]}
2   2   0   {'1_3': [0, 0, 1, 1]}
```

For aggregation, I simply want to join together the lists when the keys in the dicts in different rows of the dataframe are equal. Before aggregation, I run a groupby operation with subject and task_nr as 'groupers'. My aggregation function has a single parameter that lets me take only the last n entries from the joined list. I would like to rerun this with different parameters. However, when I rerun .agg on a groupby object derived from the dataframe multiple times, the original dataframe changes. Below are my groupby and aggregation code. I have included some deepcopies to try to avoid the problem, but it doesn't seem to help. The reason appears to be that the original dataframe is being modified. Is there a way to avoid this? Why is this happening?

```
grouped= cp.deepcopy(df4).groupby(['subject','task_nr'])  #group results by task and subject
mptd_only30 = partial(merge_probe_trial_dicts,only_last=30)  #consider only last 30 probe trials
mergag = cp.deepcopy(grouped['probe_dict']).agg(mptd_only30)  #aggregate data across sessions using function above
```

Aggregation function.

```
def merge_probe_trial_dicts(x,only_last=None):
    """ 
    Function passed as argument to result of pandas groupby in
    order to merge the dicts by subject and task
    
    Arguments:
    =========================
    x: what is passed by agg
    
    only_last (int): only look at the last n probe trials for each transition
    """
    
    out = {}
    for d in x.dropna():
        for k,v in d.items():
            if k not in out.keys():
                out[k] = v
            else:
                out[k].extend(v)
                
    if only_last:
        for k,v in out.items():
            out[k] = v[-only_last:]
    return out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `merge_probe_trial_dicts` mutates the original list that is in `df4` instead of creating a new one.

Just add `.copy()` as below and you should be good.

```py
def merge_probe_trial_dicts(x, only_last=None):
    out = {}
    for d in x.dropna():
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k not in out.keys():
                out[k] = v.copy()  # This is the trick
            else:
                out[k].extend(v)
                
    if only_last:
        for k,v in out.items():
            out[k] = v[-only_last:]
    return out
```

---

Additional trick: the extra arguments to `agg` are passed to the aggregation function. So you can directly do:

```py
df4.groupby(["subject", "task_nr"]).agg(merge_probe_trial_dicts, only_last=30)
```

instead of:

```py
mptd_only30 = partial(merge_probe_trial_dicts, only_last=30)
df4.groupby(["subject", "task_nr"]).agg(mptd_only30)
```

---

Another one: `if k not in out.keys()` is pretty inefficient since you recompute `out.keys()` each time. I suggest using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead for simpler and more efficient code:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def merge_probe_trial_dicts(x, only_last=None):
    out = defaultdict(list)
    for d in x.dropna():
        for key, value in d.items():
            out[key] += value
    if only_last is not None:
        for key, value in out.items():
            out[key] = value[-only_last:]
    return out
```